# Moving specific Google Datastore entities between App Engine apps

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

We have some entities in app A that we want to move to app B. Entities are of type User. We don't want to move *all* User entities, only a small subset, so backing up in one app and restoring in another app will not do.

One way I can think of is running a script copying one entities from one app to another, but I'm not sure what to do about keys etc.

How would I go about completely restoring them, including keys and refs etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will be able to preserve the entities' keys as-is when copying/moving across different applications since at a higher level of the datastore each application has its own namespace, with the app ID reflected/encoded in all keys of the app's entities.

One can use the [Key.app()](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/keyclass#Key_app) API to obtain the app ID from an entity key. Only the app with the ID matching the app ID encoded in an entity's key can access that entity in the datastore (otherwise IMHO GAE would have a potential serious security problem).

But it is possible to transfer the data between apps and have the destination app create its own corresponding entities with their own keys. The script would need to keep track of entities containing reference keys or IDs for other entities (which also need to be copied) and translate them accordingly. Not trivial, tho.

Answer (score 0):

When creating entities in a datastore, you have the option of specifying the key for an entity. For example,

If you're using the NDB datastore model, you can use the 'id' attribute:

```
account = Account(username='Sandy', userid=1234, email='some@where.com', id='SOME@WHERE.COM')
account.put()
account.key.id()  # returns 'SOME@WHERE.COM'
```

or

```
account = Account(username='Sandy', userid=1234, email='some@where.com')
account.key = ndb.Key('Account', 'SOME@WHERE.COM')
account.put()
```

The above example is taken from
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#creating_entities

If you're using the db datastore model, you use the 'key_name' attribute. For example:

```
employee = Employee(first_name='Antonio', last_name='Salieri', key_name='asalieri')
```

More information can be found here - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities#Python_Creating_an_entity

So basically, your code will retrieve the data from 'app A' and construct the insert statement into 'app B' using one of the above methods.